# Looking for a C++ code prettifier that will remove empty lines

Tags: c++, pretty-print

I've just taken over a large, poorly formatted mass of C++ code.
I'm looking for a code prettifier with two specific features.

- Remove superfluous access modifiers
- Clean up white space in a nice way. eg. leave blank lines between
  functions, collapse multiple blank
  lines into one within functions,
  remove blank lines between the
  opening/closing brace of a function
  and the start/end of the code.

This is a typical example. I don't want to have to write one, it'd take too long to prove that it couldn't damage the code and there's way too much to check by eye.

```
class CLASS_DECL_BASE OComStorage : public OBase
{
  private:

  protected:

  public:


      OComStorage (void );




      ~OComStorage (void );

      void Thanks_Guys();
```

Comment: isn't it easy to prove that it wouldn't damage code?  unless I'm mistaken, n whitespaces and n+1 whitespaces are logically equal, so turning any concatenation of whitespaces into 1 whitespace should be safe.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mean that removing whitespace might damage the code. I meant that I might end up doing something besides changing whitespace. I've had plenty of regexes that didn't always do what I expected.

Comment: No, n whitespaces are not the same as n+1 whitespaces.  This will damage the content of comments and literal strings.  It gets crazier:  \<newline> is significant in macros, and cyou can't just dump the newline.  You have to be sure that the prettyprinter correctly identifies real whitespace.

Comment: @bdares That assertion is immediately false for the case where n = 0.

Comment: But if n is a real number of whitespaces, then it must always be >0? Otherwise there is no whitespace.

Comment: well, in regular old c syntax at least, 1 whitespace is the same as any natural number of whitespaces.  which is what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [artistic style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/).  I've used it on a medium-sized code-base without creating any problems.  It can do a variety of source transforms on whitespace, indentation and so on.

Just make sure you back up your code (source control) while you experiment with the many, many options.  The defaults are somewhat surprising...

Answer (score 1):

See our [C++ Formatter](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/CppFormatter.html).  It processes the source code using a production lexer from a full C++ front end, so it does not/cannot misclasify a token (thus it cannot break code, say, by mishandling whitespace or change the meaning of a lexeme).

Comment: Not that it doesn't look like a effective piece of software, but artistic style seems to do everything I needed.